# react-native-vector-icons icons not showing with react native version 0.72.2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons

here is my dependency section in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "exact": "^0.8.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.2",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.0.1",
    "firebase": "^9.23.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.182.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.2",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "zustand": "^4.1.5"
  },
```

I upgraded the react native version after that I started facing this issue.

Comment: are you getting any kind of error or it is just not rendering ?

Comment: After following the installation steps in the library documentation the icon is displaying fine . React native version 0.72.3 .

Comment: no, I am not getting any error. you followed mannual instalation or normal installation flow. can you please send me your package.json

Comment: https://prnt.sc/E22itc992gtY , As , i checked for ios only i followed steps mentioned  here https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#ios